# Display different images from an action in a JSP

Tags: java, image, jsp, struts2, inputstream

I have a jsp page which iterates a list of users. Each user has his own display picture. I want to display these display pictures.

The problem is that when the page is loaded all the images are the same instead of a different image for each user.

The image tag in the iterator is this :

```
                    <img src="<s:url action="getUserImage">
                        <s:param name="user">
                             <s:property value="userId"/>
                        </s:param>
                    </s:url>"/>
```

and the action looks like this

`this.inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(user)).getDisplayPicture());`

While debugging I discovered that when executing the action for each image, the 'user' property is always the same.

The funny thing is that when I inspect the imgs elemnt on a browser, the src parameters are all correct (meaning each of them has its own different values).

I'm using spring framework, auto wiring action classes ..
struts.objectFactory value ="spring"

Comment: *"all the images are the same instead of a different image for each user. "*  Seems to contradict *"when I inspect the imgs elemnt on a browser, the src parameters are all correct (meaning each of them has its own different values)."*  Are you certain both those statements are correct?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Its funny I know. The images displayed are all the same but their src parameter is as it should be.

Comment: If the url parameters are correct but you get the same picture regardless of url parameters then your userService.getUserById must be returning the same picture every time. As such it is probably not a struts2 issue.

Comment: its not always the same image that is repeated. If i use the url on its own it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Component
@Scope("prototype")

did the trick !

action class was reusing the same id for each request

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(user)` be `userService.getUserById(Integer.parseInt(userId)` ?

Comment: <s:param name="user">.. variable which holds the user id is 'user'

Comment: If user holds an Integer why is it a String in Struts2? That is not your issue... but should be fixed.

Comment: Because I have other uses for it that require it to be a String